# How would I show the result of the boolean

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I'm supposed to take the array and check if the array is going up, but I don't understand what I'm supposed to do next. There's 2 different files..

```
public class ArrayFunHouseTwo
{
 public static boolean goingUp(int[] numArray)
 {
   for(int i = 0; i < numArray.length - 1; i++)
   {
 if(numArray[i] < numArray[i + 1])
   return true;
   }
 }
}
```

and..

```
public class ArrayFunHouseTwoRunner
{
 public static void main( String args[] )
 {
   //arrays
   int[] numArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};   
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numArray) + "\nis going Up ?");
 }
}
```

When I compile it, it looks like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
is going Up ?
```

But it's supposed to look like

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
is going Up ?  true
```

How am I supposed to get the "true" to appear?

Comment: you forgot to call `goingUp`...

Comment: Also `goingUp()` has an error.  It will return `true` if the first two elements are in ascending order, ignoring the rest of the array.

Comment: You also should consider whether this is "going up" or not: {1,2,3,3,4} (Incidentally, the term is "increasing" or "monotonic increasing; your set is monotonic increasing, while mine is increasing but not monotonic increasing)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call your method.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numArray) + "\nIs going up? " +  
    ArrayFunHouseTwo.goingUp(numArray));
```

This won't solve it though, since your method will return true every time there are 2 adjacent elements in it that increase. You should check whether two elements next to each other go down, then return false in that case, and return true in all other cases:

```
public static boolean goingUp(int[] numArray)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numArray.length - 1; i++)
    {
        if(numArray[i] >= numArray[i + 1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This way you'll know whether your array really contains only increasing elements.